# Capistrano Deploying Old Assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I'm fairly new in dealing with capistrano, learning on an inherited project.

I've done quite a few deployments on my staging server and never had a problem with the deployment dropping my CSS or JS changes in the compiled asset files.

I recently performed some major UI updates, upgrading gems for bootstrap, jquery, font awesome and others, along with major changes in my applicaiton CS and JS files.  When I deploy with capistrano on my staging server it ignores ALL of my asset changes and compiles the application JS and CSS files using old versions of the asset.  It does actually create new files, it just uses old copies of everything.  I don't see any errors when I deploy but it seems obvious that something's going wrong.

Everything works fine in development, of course, and if I run an assets:precompile locally I get all the updated CSS and JS files included.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Got this resolved.  It looks like there was a namespace collision in my deploy file (I had a :rake namespace to run some tasks) and the asset:precompile wasn't actually running. It's very annoying that it didn't crash, but instead failed silently.

Before:

```
* executing "cd -- /.../releases/20140211172000 && RAILS_ENV=qa RAILS_GROUPS=assets #<Capistrano::Configuration::Namespaces::Namespace:0x00000001868638> assets:precompile"
```

After fixing namespace collision:

```
* executing "cd -- /.../releases/20140211173407 && RAILS_ENV=qa RAILS_GROUPS=assets bundle exec rake assets:precompile"
```